# PHP Operations + Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, operations

i need some help.

I have an array ($array) - Array ( [0] => 1374410400 [1] => 1374394500 [2] => 1374384000 [3] => 1374304800 [4] => 1374291900 ).

And the operation that will be used in array is defined by the user. The operation could be array_sum, count and end.

I want to "merge" this two (array + operation), like this $operation.'('.$array.')'.

When I echo this $operation.'('.$array.')'. only appears count(Array).

But when i write "count($res)" appears the result.

Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: I have *no* idea what you're trying to do. Can you show us examples and include expected output in your question?

Comment: `echo $operation($array);`, or `echo call_user_func($operation,$array);`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need "variable variables" [See documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $operation.'('.$array.')';
```

will echo a string formed from string $operation + string ( + string $array + string ).

If you want to execute the operation whose name is stored in $operation, the simplest syntax is:

```
echo $operation($array);
```

Note: you almost certainly want to do some validation of the user's input, else you'll get a fatal error if they use an undefined function and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will only print the string, use the function to get the desired result.
    function FunctionName($operation, $array){
        if($operation =='count'){
        return count($array);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) for `call_user_func()`.

```
$results = call_user_func($operation, $array);
```

Make sure you don't allow the value of the `$operation` variable to be set directly by the user. Otherwise a malicious user could execute unwanted code on your server. Use the user input to determine which of the operations to run.